# Sample biblatex file for math?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Where might I find some sample biblatex `.bib` files, preferably with math book titles (but anything will do!)? Or bibliography files in a format readily converted to `.bib`?

I'm looking for something containing several dozen entries. I want to use this for testing.

(Hope this is not beyond the scope of tex.stackexchange!)

Comment: There's an extensive test bibliography already part of `biblatex`: it's called `biblatex-examples.bib`.  On a TL system it can be found at `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib` and accessible in a document just by using `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}`. This covers almost all of the publication types you could imagine. (92 entries in total)

Comment: `biblatex-examples.bib` as Alan suggests is certainly the first thing I'd look at. It is a bit light on `@online` entries and doesn't cover all aspects of `biblatex` features, but it should be a very good basis for tests. The subject range of the example entries is quite diverse, but there are (perhaps surprisingly) few mathematical examples. BibTeX comes with `xampl.bib` which contains quite a few artificial entries and since the file is for BibTeX it won't be using all of `biblatex`'s fields and features.

Comment: Ah, one more thing: `biblatex-examples.bib` is supposed to be usable with both `backend=biber,` and `backend=bibtex,` so it uses LaTeX-escapes for non-US-ASCII chars instead of UTF-8 (`{\"o}` instead of `ö`) and a few entries have some fields that are superfluous with Biber's enhanced `crossref` inheritance (see the `booktitle` field in `westfahl:frontier`). So a few things could be tweaked for absolute best practice if you use Biber.

Comment: Any other sources with lots of entries that are simultaneously (i) books *and* (ii) on mathematics?